# Which Site for Conceptual Computing Questions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

It seems that your site programmers exchange is being used for only code questions. My coding questions are not down voted with a few being up-voted heavily but when I ask questions regarding the state of ETL programming tools v. Query tools as they seem to overtake the need for writing code, design pattern usage other topics, I am down voted instantly. Should a new site be generated solely for conceptual questions offering help in everything from cost-efficiency to code complexity?

It would be nice to have a place where the following questions are taken as seriously as they should be.

- Conceptual questions regarding which tools to use as industries advance
- Questions regarding cost efficiency in the industry
- Questions regarding best usage of coding concepts
- Other general conceptual questions of pressing concern.

Answer (score 3):

Stack Overflow tends to focus on *applied* programming problems. For *conceptual* problems, you will probably have better luck on a site like [**Computer Sciences SE**](http://cs.stackexchange.com). They are more focused on the academic, foundational, and conceptual aspects of programming.

If your question feels like it falls somewhere in between academic and conceptual (like which tools should I use here, or how a particular methodology works, or which to apply to your specific situation), you may also want to consider [**Programmers SE**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). They tend to handle applied programming problems that fall outside actual *coding* issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think all of your points are covered by existing sites, but I'd be happy to review more specific examples if you'd like to edit one or two into your question here.

> Conceptual questions regarding which tools to use as industries advance

This will *probably* be off-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange. [Software Recommendations](//softwarerecs.stackexchange.com) will be your best bet, but I don't think they handle development tools very much. And either way, it'll be too opinion-based to simply go in search of the "right" tool when given multiple valid options.

> Questions regarding cost efficiency in the industry

[Programmers](//programmers.stackexchange.com) should be able to handle the type of question I understand this to be. Their /help/on-topic specifically lists "software engineering management," which sounds like it might be related.

If you've asked there and gotten down-voted, I'd suggest asking nicely on meta what you could do to improve your question, or confirming there that it is, in fact, totally off-topic.

> Questions regarding best usage of coding concepts

Mostly the same as above, Programmers lists "development methodologies and processes" in their scope. If they've down-voted you for questions you've asked about this, I would ask on their meta.

I wasn't sure what you meant by "coding concepts," but that might cover it.

Otherwise, if you've got functional code that you'd like a second pair of eyes on, [Code Review](//codereview.stackexchange.com) might be a good place to get algorithm implementations reviewed. It doesn't sound like that's what you're looking for, but it is another interpretation of this.

As for Stack Overflow, there are lots of questions on there about things like "why should I use this method over that one" which are well-scored and useful. As long as you've got a specific programming question (and this takes a step back from the "conceptual" bit, depending on what scope you're looking at), that could be an option.

> Other general conceptual questions of pressing concern.

This is a bit too broad to place into a particular bucket, unfortunately, but Programmers does handle a lot of conceptual questions. Stack Overflow *doesn't* (usually), as Robert Cartaino points out, so probably avoid that. But Programmers sounds like what you're looking for.